# Can an interior wall be built over an existing heat/air vent allowing air in both rooms

Tags: walls

I am looking to build an interior wall in my master bedroom to creat a walk in closet.  The best placement for the wall hits directly in the center of a current heat/air

Comment: what's the floor? hardwood? carpet? Your best bet is to move the vent to the BR, no sense in heating the closet.

Comment: The answer to this question must be "probably" because it's not clear what you're asking. You'll want to move the vent to the main room, right? Please revise to clarify.

Comment: You need a *register boot* or an *(oval) stack head*. It's probably 6" round, or oval. Might be 14x3.25 square... you'll figure it out. I'm not a fan of using walls as a chase, especially for supply air; duct it back how it should be.

Comment: @Mazura one could extend the duct itself into the interior wall...

Comment: That's part of *how it should be.* 'directly in the center' couldn't be better, unless it's perpendicular. Then you have to patch little bits of floor, and transition the duct (mangle it) which will cut it off significantly, unless you can get a *torpedo* boot in there to transition to 14x3 or oval to come up the wall a little, and then put a register boot.

Comment: There's four different combinations for ways this can possibly be run. They make fittings to do it all. The question is if you can get your hands in there to cut the duct back to make room for the fittings, or if you have to tear up some floor. Or you can cheat....

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a closet in your master bedroom , to me that is a non load bearing wall(s). This won’t be hard you just cut the bottom plate where the vent hits and move it up a foot or so. Then a wall register on each side provides the same amount of heat or possible slightly more flow because of less restriction.
I put vents in large closets to help keep air movement and reduce the chance of mold and mildew in the closet. You don’t have to duct up to the vents as these are interior walls but I would seal that short stud bay at the bottom and top to keep the air directed in the bedroom closet area.

Answer (score -1):

The amount of air flow to any room is based on “heat loss” or “heat gain”.  You do not want the same size registers In both your bedroom and closet. One room will over heat or over cool.

If the bedroom is on a corner of the house and has windows, it will have significantly more heat loss and/or heat gain.

I live in a moist environment, so a little air movement in every room (including closets) is desired to reduce mold, etc. Be careful of placing the register too low on the wall where it could be blocked.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question can a wall be built over a register location.

Comment: @EdBeal Explaining why larger vents should be in larger rooms and smaller vents in smaller rooms certainly says “yes” and how to divide the vent up proportionally. You just said “cut the bottom plate” but the wall isn’t built yet. Then you say “put a wall register on each side of the wall” without recognizing the size of each room. AND somebody down voted it too.

Comment: I also got a down vote. I did mention more flow because less restriction with common areas as master bath and closets it is quite common to split a duct like that. But the basic answer is yes then I explained how I would do it ,